# EternalBlue, PsExec and SMB versions

Tags: security

As far as I know, SMBv1 is vulnerable to EternalBlue and in that case we can get a shell via psexec. What I am asking is that, if the machine is not vulnerable to EternalBlue, does that mean we cannot access to the machine? Otherwise, how we can use use PsExec in lateral movement? are those machines vulnerable to EternalBlue and using SMBv1?

Assuming that we have the credentials of a user, we only jump to this user if this has EternalBlue vulnerability. What if the machine does not have this vulnerability?